# Vue socialite integration doesn't work on firefox or safari. (window pop-up blocker)

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome, firefox, oauth, laravel-socialite

Using oauth and vue socialite to allow for people to sign in/log in with google. Works perfectly on chrome and all google supported browsers (inc chromium). However on both safari and firefox the google popup modal to sign in with gets blocked and cannot be executed, seems to be impacted by pop-up blockers.

Comment: It's unknown what's wrong in your case. Popup blocking is specific to a browser and should be handled with trial and error.

Comment: we have done a test and it works on chrome but on firefox and safari we get a blocked pop, when the google auth window is meant to show however if we try the same thing with airbnb or others the google login window is not blocked. I really reallly need some help with this, have a hard deadline comming up.

Comment: This totally depends on what exactly you do, the question cannot be answered in general. The key for a window to not be caught by a blocker is that it always needs to be initialized by user action (click) and there should be no delay between user and open actions.